# Create UI similar to iOS contacts edit UI

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to create a UITableView where a user can remove and add cells. This table will look similar to the table when trying to edit contacts in the iOS contacts app.

[image: data cell is editable]

When the user clicks on the "+" image a new cell is created above (cell with "home" and "Phone" place holder in the image). Let's call it the "data" cell.

My understanding is that the data cell is in an "editable" state, hence the ability to delete it.

Here is my attempt to create a data cell:

```
 guard let dataCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "dataCell") else {
        self.log.error("error getting cell with reusableID plainCell")
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

dataCell.setEditing(true, animated: true)
dataCell.textLabel?.text = "Some text"
dataCell.editingAccessoryType = .detailButton
return dataCell
```

Here is what mine ends up looking like:

[image: data cell is not editable]

As you can see, my data cell is not editable. Why does `dataCell.setEditing(true, animated: true)` not work? Is this even the right approach?

Comment: I want the UITableViewCell to be editable not the view on the cell. An editable cell has editactions, i want those editactions to be visible when the cell is created.

Comment: You simply misunderstand the feature of the `setEditing` method.

Comment: @ElTomato do you understand it? Can you explain it? Do you have any pointers? I don't think the docs do a very good job because i don't get it.

Comment: Use the UITableViewCellEditingStyle method.  Its editingStyle property has three values including insert, delete, none.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using [Eureka](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka) to do that. It's pretty simple, you just have to do something like this.

```
import Eureka

class ViewController: FormViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = "Multivalued Examples"
        form +++
            MultivaluedSection(multivaluedOptions: [.Insert, .Delete]) {
                $0.tag = "textfields"
                $0.addButtonProvider = { section in
                    return ButtonRow(){
                        $0.title = "Add New Tag"
                    }.cellUpdate { cell, row in
                        cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .left
                    }
                }
            $0.multivaluedRowToInsertAt = { index in
                return NameRow() {
                    $0.placeholder = "Tag Name"
                }
            }
            $0 <<< NameRow() {
            $0.placeholder = "Tag Name"
        }
    }
}
```